# How to change The Text of TextView in Fragment from another activity

Tags: android, textview, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to change text of TextView in fragment layout from another activity.
i tried to apply various method by referring old post of this website. but those are didn't work for me.

My activity has AlertDialog box with custom title. i need to change the text of R.id.InOneFrag_amount in fragment_invone.xml using setText command when I touch the save button of custom title in AlertDialog box.how can i do that?

here is InvoBill.Java :

```
public class InvoBill extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DbAdapter dbHelper;
    View item_to_invo;
    AlertDialog ad;
    String ItmId,_qoh,_sale,_cost;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
    AutoCompleteTextView acTextView;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.customer,
            R.drawable.report,
            R.drawable.invoice
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_invo_bill);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setTitle("INVOICE#" + Invoice._id_in);

        dbHelper = new DbAdapter(this);
        dbHelper.open();

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    AddItmToInvo();
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_cus);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs_cus);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        //setupTabIcons();
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new InvOne(), "Items");
        adapter.addFragment(new InvTwo(), "Sales");
        adapter.addFragment(new InvThree(), "Payments");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

    public void AddItmToInvo(){
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_itm_to_invo_heder, null);
        ImageButton save, close;
        save = (ImageButton)myView.findViewById(R.id.btn_itm_invo_save);
        close = (ImageButton)myView.findViewById(R.id.btn_itm_invo_close);

        AlertDialog.Builder alt = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alt.setCustomTitle(myView);
        alt.setView(R.layout.item_to_invo);
        ad = alt.show();

        final int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
        final String[] from = new String[] { "_name" };

        acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)ad.findViewById(R.id.acTextView2);
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                null,
                from,
                to);
        acTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
        acTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                ItmId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
                _qoh = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_qoh"));
                _sale = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_sale")));
                _cost = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_cost")));

                if (!(_qoh.isEmpty())) {
                    ((EditText) ad.findViewById(R.id._qoh_invAdd)).
                            setText(_qoh);
                }
                if (!(_sale.isEmpty())) {
                    ((EditText) ad.findViewById(R.id._sale_invAdd)).
                            setText(_sale);
                }
            }
        });
        adapter.setCursorToStringConverter(new SimpleCursorAdapter.CursorToStringConverter() {
            @Override
            public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
                final int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_name");
                final String str = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                return str;
            }
        });
        adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            @Override
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                return dbHelper.fetchCountriesByName((constraint != null ? constraint.toString() : null));
            }
        });
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    EditText qty, rate;
                    qty = (EditText) ad.findViewById(R.id._qoh_invAdd);
                    rate = (EditText) ad.findViewById(R.id._sale_invAdd);

                    dbHelper.AddUpInvItm(Invoice._id_in, ItmId, qty.getText().toString(), rate.getText().
                            toString(), String.valueOf(Float.valueOf(qty.getText().toString()) *
                            Float.valueOf(rate.getText().toString())), String.valueOf(Float.
                            valueOf(qty.getText().toString()) * Float.valueOf(_cost)));
                    dbHelper.AdjustQoh(ItmId, String.valueOf(Float.valueOf(_qoh)
                            - Float.valueOf(qty.getText().toString())));

                    //I need setText for R.id.InOneFrag_amount in fragment_invone.xml from here.

                    ad.dismiss();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ad.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

here is my InvOne.Java activity:

```
public class InvOne extends Fragment{

    String[] columns;
    int[] to;
    Cursor cursor;
    ListView listView;
    TextView myTextView;
    private DbAdapter dbHelper;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

    public InvOne() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dbHelper = new DbAdapter(getContext());
        dbHelper.open();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflat, ViewGroup container,
                              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflat.inflate(R.layout.fragment_invone, container, false);

        //I set default value to R.id.InOneFrag_amount from here.
        myTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.InOneFrag_amount);
        myTextView.setText("test");
        displayListView(v);
        return v;
    }

    public void displayListView(View v){
        try{
            cursor = dbHelper.fetchInvoItemById(Invoice._id_in);
            columns = new String[] {
                    DbAdapter.InvoItm_COL_5,
                    DbAdapter.InvoItm_COL_6,
                    DbAdapter.InvoItm_COL_7,
                    DbAdapter.InvoItm_COL_7,
            };
            to = new int[] {
                    R.id.InvItm_qty,
                    R.id.InvItm_rate,
                    R.id.InvItm_amount,
                    R.id.InvItm_des,
            };
            dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    getContext(), R.layout.row_inv_itm,
                    cursor,
                    columns,
                    to,
                    0);

            listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.lViewFragInvOne);
            listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

            listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.v("Error ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change text of textView from another activity:

Code in activity-1:

```
private void goToActivity(Class<?extends Activity> activityClass,String text)
{
    Intent newActivity24=new Intent(this,activityClass);
    newActivity24.putExtra("key",text);
    startActivity(newActivity24);
}
```

code in activity-2:

```
TextView steamB=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);


    String textChange=getIntent().getExtras().get("key").toString();
    steamB.setText(textChange);
```

Comment: Error:(55, 28) error: cannot find symbol method getIntent()

Answer (score 0):

Create a new public method in your first activity like this

```
public void setTextofTextView(String text)
{
     textView.setText(text);
}
```

and pass your activity instance into the other activity. Then from the other activity, call this whenever you need it.

```
((FirstActivity)activity).setTextofTextView("new text");
```

Comment: when calling invOne instance, pass activity like this  new InvOne(InvoBill.this) and create a constructor in ur fragment that accepts an input parameter of type Activity

Comment: I put public void setTextofTextView(String text){textView.setText(text);} into InvOne fragment activity file. but i can't understand how can i call this method from my main activity.. please explain it. i'm new to the program field and android.

Comment: Follow the code I put. put the method in the activity whose textview u want to modify, put the second code line in the other activity from which you are changing it and put the type cast accordingly.

Comment: If activity names are A and B, and u want to call a method defined in A from B, do ((A)activity).method() - typecast to A. and activity you pass when you are creating the instance of B from A like this : new B(A.this), and in your constructor in B, define it as public B(Activity activity){this.activity = activity;} after creating a class variable "activity" in B.